# Is there any indication when a task is done using FullCalendar within FileMaker?

Tags: fullcalendar, filemaker

I'm using FullCalendar in Filemaker and was wondering if there is any way to indicate when a task is done?  Keep it on the calendar but show the text crossed out or 'X' through the box or something like that.

Comment: There's no built-in way, but the eventRender callback (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventRender) allows you to modify the HTML of an event, so you can change its appearance when it's being drawn on the calendar. And you could use a custom property of the event (see the "Non-standard fields" section at https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-object) to help your code determine whether to change the event's appearance to show it as completed.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the info and pointing me in the right direction.